# tflearn with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I can't import tflearn with TensorFlow 2.0

```
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import tflearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/summarizer.py", line 9, in <module>
    merge_summary = tf.summary.merge
AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'merge'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .dnn import DNN
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..helpers.trainer import Trainer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .evaluator import Evaluator
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/evaluator.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .trainer import evaluate_flow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .summarizer import summaries, summarize, summarize_gradients, \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/summarizer.py", line 12, in <module>
    merge_summary = tf.merge_summary
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'merge_summary'
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I really need it to get solved as soon as possible.
I am pretty much new to tensorflow.

Answer (score 6):

As of today, [`tflearn`](https://pypi.org/project/tflearn/) (v0.3.2) is not TensorFlow 2.0 ready, and specifically requires TF 1.x. I'm sure it will get updated at some point but for now, if you need tflearn, use TF 1.

---

I get a different error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'` since `contrib` has been moved to `tensorflow_addons`, and the [pypi package is currently for Linux only](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/142#issuecomment-480127104).

---

**Dec '20 update:** [v0.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/tflearn/0.5.0/#history) (released Nov '20) supports [TF2, exclusively](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn#readme).

> Note: Latest TFLearn (v0.5) is only compatible with TensorFlow v2.0 and over.

And make sure to import it correctly:

> ```
> import tflearn
> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
> ```